# Java Stream: Flat from Pair<K, Object[]> to Pair<K, Object>

Tags: java, java-stream, apache-commons

I need to flat a stream of `Pair<Application, FileObject[]>`, to a stream of `Pair<Application, FileObject>`.

Currently, I've coded that:

```
List<Application> applications = this.applicationDao.findAll();
applications.stream()
    .map(app -> 
        new Pair<Application, FileObject[]>(
            app,
            this.massiveInterfaceService.getPendingDocuments(app)
        )
    );
```

So, what I need is to get an stream of `Pair<app, FileObject>`.

`this.massiveInterfaceService.getPendingDocuments` is:

```
public Stream<FileObject> getPendingDocuments(Application app) { /*...*/ }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `Pair` coming from?

Comment: from `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple`

Comment: can `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` be instantiated with that construct?

Comment: @nullpointer is right, probably you need to use the static method `Pair.of()`

Comment: Another confusing part in the question though is *`Pair<Application, FileObject[]`*, how can `getPendingDocuments` return a `Stream<FileObject>` at the same time. I doubt the code in the question would even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call `flatMap`, creating a stream off the result of `getPendingDocuments`. This is because `getPendingDocuments` already returns a stream.

```
applications.stream()
   .flatMap(app -> this.massiveInterfaceService
                    .getPendingDocuments(app)
                    .map(doc -> Pair.of(app, doc));
```

Comment: the confusing part in the question though is *`Pair<Application, FileObject[]`*, how can `getPendingDocuments` return a `Stream<FileObject>` at the same time. I doubt the code in the question would even compile.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `massiveInterfaceService.getPendingDocuments()` returns `FileObject[]`, you can create a method like this:

```
Stream<Pair<Application, FileObject>> flatten(Pair<Application, FileObject[]> pair) {
   return Arrays.stream(pair.getRight())
                .map(fileObject -> new Pair.of(pair.getLeft(), fileObject));
}
```

Then use it in your stream:

```
Stream<Pair<Application, FileObject>> stream =
   applications.stream()
        .map(app -> 
            Pair.of(app, this.massiveInterfaceService.getPendingDocuments(app)))
        .flatMap(this::flatten);
```

If on the other hand `massiveInterfaceService.getPendingDocuments()` returns a `Stream<FileObject>`

```
Stream<Pair<Application, FileObject>> stream =
   applications.stream()
        .flatMap(app -> 
            this.massiveInterfaceService
                .getPendingDocuments(app)))
                .map(fileObject -> Pair.of(app, fileObject)));
```

It is not clear from your question which is the right one.